# GPS and Time Activated Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, push-notification, gps, gps-time

I'm trying to send push notifications to users when they are at a specific location for more than 5 min. I know that you can send push notifications when a user is at a specific location, but how exactly do I "delay" the push notification 5 min?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably what you want:

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

More info in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).